# When does "This Is Gallifrey: Our Childhood. Our Home" play?

Tags: doctor-who, music

I'm listening to the Doctor Who soundtrack on spotify and fell in love with "This Is Gallifrey: Our Childhood. Our Home". However, I have no idea when it actually plays. From the playlist order I assume it plays in "The Last of the Time Lords" but I can't think of when exactly. Can anyone provide details?

Comment: A related question about the same piece of music is https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179758/ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Re-watching them to try and find more instances, but I remember it from '[The Sound of Drums](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sound_of_Drums)' and '[The Last of the Timerlords](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Last_of_the_Time_Lords).'

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who%3a_Original_Television_Soundtrack_-_Series_3), tho:

> "This is Gallifrey: Our Childhood, Our Home":
>   Three-parter: "Utopia" / "The Sound of Drums" / "Last of the Time Lords", "The Doctor's Daughter", "The End of Time", pattern used in the Series 6 Soundtrack

So, it looks like it's in 5 episodes.  So far, I've spotted it during the Flashbacks, where he talks about the [Untempered Schism](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Untempered_Schism) and during the the Master's funeral pyre scene.   I'll keep hunting; without watching, I would guess the occurrence in [The Doctor's Daughter](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_Daughter) is at the funeral scene.

Update:  During 'The Doctor's Daughter', when he's explaining what a Timelord is, it plays in the background.  Just past 16 minutes into the episode.

I suspect, however, that it's used as a [leitmotif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitmotif) all thru several season, whenever Gallifrey is mentioned.  **Update**: Ok; I'm stopping now.. it's used as a leitmotif ALL OVER the place.. The sad oboe portion, the opening.. Bah.. Too many to list.. but the list I've given gives some places you can hear larger amounts of it.

Comment: A fairly good same of some of the scenes can be found in this [Youtube video:](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iN6tnXW5mUo)

Comment: Hehe, I found that video but assumed that it was a collection of clips not immediately connected the the music itself ;)

Comment: @AntonMårtensson - it's not perfect, but most of them do have it either playing, or about to play.  The hard part is that this piece has several different sounding movements, so it's not that easy to instantly spot.

Answer (score -1):

- Utopia
- The Tenth Doctor meets Professor Yana
- The Doctor fixes Yana's machine
- Yana tells the Doctor about his alleged childhood
- Yana begins regaining his memories of his true identity
- The Sound of Drums
- The Doctor, Martha Jones, and Jack Harkness run for their lives
- The Doctor describes Gallifrey and the source of the Master's insanity
- Last of the Time Lords
- The Master dies in the Doctor's arms and refuses to regenerate
- The Doctor's Daughter
- The Doctor describes how Gallifrey was destroyed in the Last Great Time War
- The End of Time
- The Master talks to the Tenth Doctor about their childhoods on Gallifrey and what they have become.
- Rassilon and the Time Lords meet on Gallifrey to discuss the war.
- The Name of the Doctor
- The First Doctor steals the TARDIS on Gallifrey and runs into Clara Oswald.
- Clara encounters multiple other incarnations of the Doctor
- Clara tells the Eleventh Doctor about the message she received regarding Trenzalore
- The Time of the Doctor
- The Time Lords send the Eleventh Doctor a new regeneration cycle through a crack in time as he is about to die.

Comment: Are these a list of all the instances the song was played, or is this just a wall of text?