# Doctor Who s3 soundtrack This is Gallifrey

Tags: doctor-who

This is Gallifrey, 23rd track on Doctor Who Series 3 soundtrack has an excerpt from a different theme from 1:14  , but I can't remember it's name. Please reply if you know it.

No Spoilers from after Journey's End please.

Comment: Well, this is NOT a site to ask for song suggestions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would be on-topic @Shreedhar.  It's production relevant, even if it's nothing to do with plot or character, it's still about the music in the show.

Comment: @Radhil I guess the questions here are/should be related to the show and not something like its soundtrack. Well, at least that's what I have seen here till now. I guess someone more well-versed with this site may be a better judge than me.

Comment: @Shreedhar - yeah, not very common compared to other questions, but I typed 'soundtrack' into the search bar and we have a bunch.  Think of it as fan-related; hell, half the time I go back to old RPGs it's because I like the music.

Comment: Well then I guess I need to take back my flag! Apologies to both Harveen and @Radhil. Thanks for letting me know about it.

Comment: @Shreedhar I think thematic phrasing in a soundtrack for a show like Doctor Who is quite important - as you watch the series you will hear all sorts of callbacks, to the extent that it can even end up foreshadowing. This is a bit different to asking "what was the pop song playing when Starlord first steals the inifity orb".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remember it probably because it's the theme that plays [for the Master's funeral in "Last of the Time Lords"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6k5Qc1Qb4I&t=164s).